# Wrapper design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Say I have a class:

```
class B;
class A{
public:
    A();
    virtual B foo();
}
```

defined in a 3rd party component. I want to wrap classes A and B, resulting myA and myB.
Now, I shouldn't be able to access class A and class B from the outside, but rather have the same functionality for myA and myB. foo() could be called from the 3rd party module.

I would prefer to do this using inheritence, not encapsulation.

So there are 2 problems:

1. Calling a->myFoo()  (need to rename methods because of same signature and different return type)  should call A::foo() if a is of type myA.
2. Calling a->myFoo() should call myA2::myFoo() if a is of type class myA2::myA.

Any suggestions on how to do this elegantly? I came up with some solutions but I prefer a fresh view on the whole thing.

EDIT:

Just a theoretical question. I don't actually need to do this, just thinking of ways it can be achieved.

EDIT2:

myA2 is a class that extends myA. Before the pattern, it would have been called A2 (a class that extended the class A from the 3rd party module).

Comment: Despite your stated preference, you should use encapsulation, not inheritance for this.  With encapsulation, you can isolate all dependencies on the third-party library.

Comment: Luchian: `myA` wraps `A` and `myB` wraps `B`, but what is `myA2`?

Comment: myA2 extends myA. Check out the second edit.

Comment: I hate theoretical questions.  If you have a specfic use case which requires you to consider choosing anything other than current best practice please give us the details.  Otherwise, ask it on programmers.stackexchange.com where such questions belong.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you prefer to do this with inheritance instead of encapsulation. Generally speaking, extending the class you're wrapping is the "wrong" way to implement the wrapper pattern, especially since you generally want to redefine the interface in the process. In class myA, you'll have a field of type A that contains an instance of class A, which methods in myA can call upon as needed. Unless I've misunderstood what you want to accomplish, this is the most elegant way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I know, but I'm looking for the most elegant way without encapsulation. Purely theoretical...

Comment: @Luchian Grigore Why would you intentionally preclude yourself from the best approach even for a theoretical question?

Comment: So you're just exploring ways implement the wrapper pattern that are manifestly worse than composition? Um, okay.

Comment: Best approach that we know of. :P

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare the function names/parameters similarly.  Check out:
[strange-inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9) section: [23.9] What's the meaning of, Warning: `Derived::f(char)` hides `Base::f(double)`? on the 3rd code block.

It also shows the syntax for calling base methods.

Comment: That doesn't apply. In that case, parameters differ. In my case, return types differ. The compiler will throw an error, not a warning.

Comment: Read farther, the 3rd codeblock redefines the same parameters/function name and uses base syntax to recall the base version of the function.  So it's hidden behind the interface like you asked.